# Why do my variadic functions in my printf function not work?

Tags: c, printf, variadic-functions, stdio, variadic

I need to recreate the `printf` function for a school project. My current function works flawlessly, except if there are two arguments.

If I do the following: `ft_printf("%c%c", 'a', 'b');`

it will print `aa`, instead of `ab`.

If I do the following: `ft_printf("%c%d", 't', 29);`

it will not print `t29` like it's supposed to.
Instead, it will print `t116` as it does detect that I would like to print an int, but doesn't use the right argument (it converts "t" in its ascii value (116)).

I have included below the code of my main `printf`function, the ft_analysis function (to find the flags), the ft_utilities_one function (which has some basic functions like putchar() for example) as well as the parsing function I'm using to parse the string given as primary argument. Due to how many code there is, I have only included the `char` printing function (ft_c_craft) as an example. If you need more clarity regarding how these functions are used, you can find [here my printf repository](https://github.com/maxdesalle/42/tree/main/ft_printf).

ft_printf.c

```
int ft_printf(const char *str, ...)
{
    t_list  box;
    va_list argptr;

    va_start(argptr, str);
    ft_parser(argptr, (char *)str, &box);
    va_end(argptr);
    return (box.len);
}
```

ft_parser.c

```
static void ft_craft1(va_list argptr, t_list *box)
{
    if (box->type == 'c')
        ft_c_craft(va_arg(argptr, int), box);
    else if (box->type == 's')
        ft_s_craft(va_arg(argptr, char *), box);
    else if (box->type == 'd' || box->type == 'i')
        ft_di_craft(va_arg(argptr, int), box);
}

static void ft_craft2(va_list argptr, t_list *box)
{
    if (box->type == 'u')
        ft_u_craft(va_arg(argptr, unsigned int), box);
    else if (box->type == 'x')
        ft_xx_craft(va_arg(argptr, int), 0, box);
    else if (box->type == 'X')
        ft_xx_craft(va_arg(argptr, int), 1, box);
    else if (box->type == 'p')
        ft_p_craft(va_arg(argptr, unsigned long long), box);
}

static void ft_type_selector(va_list argptr, t_list *box)
{
    if (box->type == 'c' || box->type == 's' || box->type == 'd'
            || box->type == 'i')
        ft_craft1(argptr, box);
    else
        ft_craft2(argptr, box);
}

void        ft_parser(va_list argptr, char *str, t_list *box)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (str[i] == '%' && str[i + 1] != '%')
        {
            ft_analysis(&str[++i], box);
            while (ft_strchr("cspdiuxX", str[i]) == NULL)
                i++;
            if (ft_strchr("cspdiuxX", str[i]))
                box->type = str[i];
            ft_type_selector(argptr, box);
        }
        else if (str[i] == '%' && str[i + 1] == '%')
            ft_putchar(str[++i], box);
        else
            ft_putchar(str[i], box);
        i++;
    }
}
```

ft_analysis.c

```
static void ft_precision(char *str, t_list *box)
{
    box->precision = 0;
    while (*str != '\0')
    {
        if (*str == '.')
        {
            box->precision = ft_atoi_alpha(++str);
            return ;
        }
        str++;
    }
    return ;
}

static void ft_width(char *str, t_list *box)
{
    box->width = 0;
    while (*str != '\0' && *str != '.')
    {
        if (*str >= '0' && *str <= '9')
        {
            box->width = ft_atoi_alpha(str);
            return ;
        }
        str++;
    }
    return ;
}

static void ft_flag(char *str, t_list *box)
{
    box->fzero = 0;
    box->fplus = 0;
    box->fminus = 0;
    box->fspace = 0;
    while (*str != '\0' && (!(*str >= '1' && *str <= '9')))
        if (*str++ == '0')
            box->fzero += 1;
    else if (ft_strchr(str, '+'))
        box->fplus += 1;
    else if (ft_strchr(str, '-'))
        box->fminus += 1;
    else if (ft_strchr(str, ' '))
        box->fspace += 1;
    return ;
}

void        ft_analysis(char *str, t_list *box)
{
    ft_precision(str, box);
    ft_width(str, box);
    ft_flag(str, box);
}
```

ft_c_craft.c

```
static void ft_print_char(char c, t_list *box)
{
    if (box->fminus == 1)
    {
        ft_putchar(c, box);
        ft_super_putchar(box->width - 1, ' ', box);
        return ;
    }
    else if (box->fzero == 1)
        ft_super_putchar(box->width - 1, '0', box);
    else if (box->fminus == 0)
        ft_super_putchar(box->width - 1, ' ', box);
    ft_putchar(c, box);
    return ;
}

void    ft_c_craft(char c, t_list *box)
{
    if (box->width > 1)
        ft_print_char(c, box);
    else
        ft_putchar(c, box);
}
```

ft_utilities_one.c

```
void    ft_putchar(char c, t_list *box)
{
    write(1, &c, 1);
    box->len += 1;
}

void    ft_putstr(char *str, t_list *box)
{
    while (*str != '\0')
    {
        write(1, str++, 1);
        box->len += 1;
    }
}

void    ft_putstr_precision(char *str, t_list *box)
{
    int i;

    i = box->precision;
    while (*str != '\0' && i-- > 0)
    {
        write(1, str++, 1);
        box->len += 1;
    }
}   

void    ft_super_putchar(int len, char c, t_list *box)
{
    while (len-- > 0)
    {
        write(1, &c, 1);
        box->len += 1;
    }
}

long    ft_atoi_alpha(const char *nptr)
{
    long    result;

    result = 0;
    while (*nptr && ((*nptr >= 9 && *nptr <= 13) || *nptr == ' '))
        nptr++;
    if (*nptr == '-' || *nptr == '+')
        nptr++;
    while (*nptr && *nptr >= '0' && *nptr <= '9')
        result = result * 10 + (*nptr++ - '0');
    return (result);
}
```

Comment: Which is why I have included the link to the repository with all the code. You can find it here: https://github.com/maxdesalle/42/tree/main/ft_printf

Comment: t_list is a linked list where I store all the data about the arguments, including the width, precision, flags,...

Comment: ft_c_craft, ft_s_craft,... are the functions which are in charge of printing the arguments, following the data stored inside the box (the linked list).

Comment: Apologies, I'm new to stackoverflow. Let me edit my question.

Comment: That's an awful lot of code to read, whether here or offsite.  And just leaving out the parts that you don't think are relevant doesn't help, because then nobody can build it.  Read again the link that Bruno posted.  The idea is to actually *reduce* your program to a much smaller one that only contains what's needed to reproduce the bug. It should still be a complete program that someone can compile and run (preferably in just one file), so for instance, if you cut out a function that isn't relevant, you'll also need to cut out the code that calls it

Comment: Teach yourself to use for() loops.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Nate. Appreciate it.

Comment: Can't use for loops due to the rules imposed by my school.

Comment: **Study for inspiration** the source code of existing open source implementations of `printf`, e.g. in https://musl-.libc.org/ but **mention that explicitly to your teacher**

Comment: I'd recommend you to read the implementation from the old Unix source code.  Besides it can be old C code style, it is simpler enough so it doesn't burden you with the today's complexities of `printf()` implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I do the following: `ft_printf("%c%c", 'a', 'b');`
>
> it will print aa, instead of ab.
>
> If I do the following: `ft_printf("%c%d", 't', 29);`
>
> it will not print t29 like it's supposed to. Instead, it will print t116 as it does detect that I would like to print an int, but doesn't use the right argument (it converts "t" in its ascii value (116)).

visibly you do not progress and always use the first argument, this is because you give the *va_list* by value, so you use a copy of it and you cannot progress in the list of argument. Just give it by pointer

in *ft_printf*

```
ft_parser(&argptr, (char *)str, &box);
```

and :

```
static void ft_craft1(va_list *argptr, t_list *box)
{
    if (box->type == 'c')
        ft_c_craft(va_arg(*argptr, int), box);
    else if (box->type == 's')
        ft_s_craft(va_arg(*argptr, char *), box);
    else if (box->type == 'd' || box->type == 'i')
        ft_di_craft(va_arg(*argptr, int), box);
}
```

etc

Comment: Thank you so much, it works now. Really appreciate. I will make sure to ask more concise questions, while keeping the clarity a priority of course. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @max yes, of course is not easy to put the right part of code when not knowing where the problem is, but in our side difficult to manage a big code ;-) Anyway your remarks about your tries was very right , I do not read them enough seriously first looking at the code

Answer (score 0):

Use `switch() case` as in this simple example

```
int ts_formatstring(char *buf, const char *fmt, va_list va)
{
    char *start_buf = buf;
    while(*fmt)
    {
        /* Character needs formating? */
        if (*fmt == '%')
        {
            switch (*(++fmt))
            {
              case 'c':
                *buf++ = va_arg(va, int);
                break;
              case 'd':
              case 'i':
                {
                    signed int val = va_arg(va, signed int);
                    if (val < 0)
                    {
                        val *= -1;
                        *buf++ = '-';
                    }
                    ts_itoa(&buf, val, 10);
                }
                break;
              case 's':
                {
                    char * arg = va_arg(va, char *);
                    while (*arg)
                    {
                        *buf++ = *arg++;
                    }
                }
                break;
              case 'u':
                    ts_itoa(&buf, va_arg(va, unsigned int), 10);
                break;
              case 'x':
              case 'X':
                    ts_itoa(&buf, va_arg(va, int), 16);
                break;
              case '%':
                  *buf++ = '%';
                  break;
            }
            fmt++;
        }
        /* Else just copy */
        else
        {
            *buf++ = *fmt++;
        }
    }
    *buf = 0;

    return (int)(buf - start_buf);
}
```

PS not mycode it is from atollic - used for example purposes. Sme potential UBs.

Comment: Can't use switch due to the rules imposed by my school...

Comment: @Max Then use an if/else chain.

Comment: Thanks guys, but how does that help me exactly? Why aren't my variadic functions working correctly?

Comment: @max Debug your program. All modern IDEs support GUI debugging. Step through your code